# Should I buy or hack a 240v remote controlled thermostat?

Tags: electrical, heating

I'd like to buy/easily create a thermostat that remotely controls a 240v / 10A switch.  At a minimum the switch should be on when it's hot, and the threshold should be configurable. Digital temperature settings and inverted on/off a bonus!

The usage is to control a an electric heater that normally plugs into the wall and has a built-in thermostat. By plugging into the remote controlled switch and setting the built in thermostat to max, the heater will respond to the ambient temperature at the remote thermostat which I'm hoping will be more stable than the local temperature in the heater casing.

Answer (score 1):

240V thermostats (of 10A capacity or usually greater) are easily bought off the shelf - they are commonly used to control electric baseboard heat from a wall-mount box. You could mount one in a freestanding box if you want this "portable" as well, or you could wall-mount one and have it control a (labeled) outlet that the heater would plug into.

While you could also use any thermostat and a relay with a suitable coil voltage for the thermostat, that's just more parts and complexity for a problem that there's a one-peice solution to, commonly available.